# Access local variables context of nodejs main from included eval script

Tags: node.js, include, eval

I have found the following way to include nodejs files rather handy without converting them to modules. There is only one small caveat. I would prefer not have to change my var to global in main.js so it can be accessible by the included.js file. As you can see in the included file I do not have to do that. And the variables there are accessible my main. See code. Is there someway that the local context of the main file of node can be accessed in the included file withouting having to resort to changing all var.* to global.* if I want them access by the include.

Here is the code

//Main file

```
//evalmain.js
var vm = require('vm');
var fs=require("fs");

global.globalVar = 0;  //<<-- *** Prefer var globalVar***

// Include the script 
var script = new vm.Script(fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"\\evalinc.js"+""));
script.runInThisContext();

console.log("globalVar: ", globalVar, "  evalVar: ", evalVar);
showvars();
console.log("globalVar: ",++globalVar, "  evalVar: ", evalVar);
evalVar="Now set in evalmain";
showvars();
```

//Include file

```
// evalinc.js is the file to be included
// Note, it's not a module. Just plain JS
debugger;
globalVar=100; // Sets the global variable at main!
var evalVar="Set in evalinc!";
var showvars=function(){
    console.log("globalVar: ",++globalVar, "  evalVar: ", evalVar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the local variable context is not programmatically accessible. You can however create a dedicated object that will become the context for the script:

```
var vm = require('vm');
var fs=require("fs");

var globals = {
    globalVar: 0
}; // not a global variable

// Include the script 
var script = new vm.Script(fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"\\evalinc.js"+""));
script.runInNewContext(globals);

console.log("globalVar: ", globals.globalVar, "  evalVar: ", globals.evalVar);
globals.showvars();
console.log("globalVar: ", ++globals.globalVar, "  evalVar: ", globals.evalVar);
globals.evalVar="Now set in evalmain";
globals.showvars();
```

Comment: There are many other ways to skin the cat. I was looking for a way without modifying my code nor the included/eval code. My solution is simpler, because all I had to do was modify the global variable declarations in my code. ie var globalVar =0 --> global. globalVar = 0. What is even more interesting you can remove the var declaration and initialize the variable as just globalVar=0 and you would get same effect. But still modifies code. With all introspection of node, you would think there would be a way to access programmatically the local context.

Comment: No, I don't think there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a simple `eval`? I guess it does exactly the magic that you are expecting here, even without affecting the global scope.

```
var fs=require("fs");

var globalVar = 0;

eval(fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"\\evalinc.js")); // Include the script 

console.log("globalVar: ", globalVar, "  evalVar: ", evalVar);
showvars();
console.log("globalVar: ", ++globalVar, "  evalVar: ", evalVar);
evalVar = "Now set in evalmain";
showvars();
```